# Finding all longest paths given edges of a directed graph

Tags: graph-theory

I have a list of IDs and Successor IDs like so:

ID -> Successor ID

1 -> 2

1 -> 3

2 -> 3

5 -> 2

From this list I am hoping to calculate all the longest paths between all terminal nodes (no predecessors e.g. 1 in this example, or no successors e.g. 3 in this example):

1 2 3

5 2 3

I have looked into breadth/depth first traversals but can't seem to find an implementation that will handle the structure of my input (I have ~1000 rows). I believe it is safe to assume there are no cycles.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is the path "1 2 3" not longer than the path "1 3"? Why would "1 3" be a result?

Comment: yeah you are right - changed it